# Creating .exe file from python package for windows10

Tags: windows-10, exe, pyinstaller, pyside2

I implemented one package with GUI based on Pyside2. This package has the following structure:

- Repository

  - Function
  - GUI_class
  - Main_GUI.py

It means Main_GUI.py use some classes and function in GUI and Function folders. Now I want to create the executable version from it for windows 10. I tried Pyinstaller for this aim like the following comments:

> (conda env)F:\Repository> Pyinstaller Main_GUI.py

But when I run the *.exe file in dist folder it gives me the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'
>
> Blockquote[15728] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgre

Would you please help me how can I convert this python package to *.exe? Thank you in advance.

These are my  version of my dependencies:
Python 3.6.10,
Pyinstaller 3.6,
Pyside2 5.13.2.

Comment: Maybe you could add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I've used pyinstaller before, but never with anaconda or a conda environment (it looks like you are).

Comment: Problem was solved by update python version to the latest version and installing Pyinstaller with the following comment: pip3 install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/python3.zip